# Cannot import enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 with wikitaxi_importer.exe

Tags: database

I have downloaded the enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2 data dump from Wikipedia but when i open the Wikitaxi_importer.exe and browse for the xml.bz2 file and select it, it does not appear in the line.  The file is in .rar format, do I nned to extract it before trying to run Wikitaxi_importer.exe to create a database?  Is there a setting on the file I need to change?  The instructions in the box say "read only" but when I tried switching the xml.bz2 file to read only, i get an error.  Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download#WikiTaxi_usage

(It seems you're ignoring step 3, which says in part, "The importer takes care to uncompress the dump as it imports, so make sure to save your drive space and do not uncompress beforehand."

You seem to think .bz2 files are in .rar format; that's not true.  See http://www.bzip.org …)